# Xcode Swift error with Braintree SDK

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to integrate the braintree sdk payment system into my app.  I've done everything in the instructions (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v3) and I'm getting a strange error.  Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func purchase(sender: AnyObject) {
      let dropInViewController: BTDropInViewController = braintree!.dropInViewControllerWithDelegate(self)
      dropInViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: Selector("userDidCancel"))            
      dropInViewController.summaryTitle = "Pass"
      dropInViewController.summaryDescription = "Purchase the product"
      dropInViewController.displayAmount = "$5"

    var navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dropInViewController)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and here's the error I'm getting when I touch the button to show the Braintree Drop In View

```
2015-12-15 20:06:39.764 TheDiner[1169:22409] +[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104e4abc8
2015-12-15 20:06:39.828 TheDiner[1169:22409] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104e4abc8'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010565bc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001061dcbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105662fad +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055b913c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055b8cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TheDiner                            0x0000000103004f70 -[BTUI borderColor] + 64
    6   TheDiner                            0x0000000102fd8564 -[BTDropInContentView initWithFrame:] + 964
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001040d7393 -[UIView init] + 62
    8   TheDiner                            0x00000001030f794e -[BTUIThemedView init] + 62
    9   TheDiner                            0x0000000102fe0cb2 -[BTDropInViewController initWithClient:] + 226
    10  TheDiner                            0x0000000102fbfba1 -[Braintree dropInViewControllerWithDelegate:] + 209
    11  TheDiner                            0x0000000102fa9e7c _TFC8TheDiner22ZiftPassViewController16purchaseZiftPassfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 572
    12  TheDiner                            0x0000000102faa206 _TToFC8TheDiner22ZiftPassViewController16purchaseZiftPassfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104075d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010418750a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001041868d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001040c2958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001040c3282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104089541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104096cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010407159c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010558f431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055852fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105584934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105584366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107c0fa3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001040748c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  TheDiner                            0x0000000102fbea37 main + 135
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010694d145 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

I'm using Xcode 6 for ios8.  I have the braintree header file in the bridging header.

```
#import <Braintree/Braintree.h>
#endif
```

Please point me in the right direction I've been stuck on this for a few hours.  I'm thinking maybe I need to import another header in my bridge file but when I do it gives errors as well.  Thanks

Comment: I'm using a Podfile for the Braintree SDK btw

Answer (score 0):

So the issue causing the crash is this:

```
5   TheDiner                            0x0000000103004f70 -[BTUI borderColor] + 64
```

It appears that borderColor is a class method on BTUI, but that method calls `+[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]`, and the runtime can't find the implementation for `+[UIColor bt_colorWithBytesR:G:B:]`. This method is defined in UIColor+BTUI.h

Make sure you that you were able to import all of the headers for Brain Tree in the bridging header if you are using swift.

Try importing the header for the category file UIColor+BTUI.h manually in the bridging header and do a clean build and try again....

**Updated Steps:**
I got this to work, looks like something is messed up in your project file... I ran into the same problems you were having. But try these steps:

1) Create a new xcode project, (no need for bridged headers file).

2) Then change your podfile to:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'Braintree', '~> 3.9'
```

then do a pod update 
3)then at the top of your ViewController class add `import Braintree` then do a clean build

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I added these 2 lines to the bridge header:    #import <Braintree/UIColor+BTUI.h>
#import <Braintree/BTUI.h>  
I'm still getting errors after clean and build.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: I have uploaded a sample of the code to github. (https://github.com/kbondsii/braintree_issues)

Comment: @KJBonds I got this to work, looks like something is messed up in your project file though I ran into the same problems you were having. But try these steps: Create a new xcode project, (no need for bridged headers file). Then change your podfile to `use_frameworks!
pod 'Braintree', '~> 3.9'` then do a `pod update` then at the top of your ViewController class add `import Braintree` then do a clean build

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot this afternoon.

Comment: Commander147, This didn't work.  I created a new project and used the new Podfile line.  It now gives me some Mach-O error (screenshot: http://i65.tinypic.com/2ronfra.png).  I googled this error and tried everything I see with no results.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong at all.

Comment: btw, is the project Pods supposed to look the same as when I didn't "use_frameworks!"?  I see a suitcase icon in other projects but mine doesn't look any different